# How to fetch data from mongoDB based on two dates in spring boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm using Aggregation in spring boot. but getting response as null

```
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("createdAt").lt(fromDate).gt(toDate));
```

mongoDbTemplate returning query as follows

```
"createdAt" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2020-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2022-01-04T07:34:42.000Z"}}}}
```

so how to fetch data from MongoDB using mongoTemplate.aggregation.
$date is not supported in mongo Shell,
is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `and` in case you want to get range [from,to]

```
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("createdAt").lt(fromDate)
                                     .and("createdAt").gt(toDate));
```

Alternatively,

`Criteria` class has `andOperator` function. You need to pass your conditions to that.

```
query.addCriteria(
    new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where("createdAt").lt(fromDate),
        Criteria.where("createdAt").gt(toDate)
    )
);
```

Another option is query annotation.

`@Query("{'createdAt' : { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 } }")`

Here, `?0` represents first argument to the function, `?1` represents second argument to the function.

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#and-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I tried this but comparing String type. I have to compare Date type query.addCriteria(
    new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where("createdAt").lt(fromDate),
        Criteria.where("createdAt").gt(toDate)
    )
);

Comment: also I have refer other QA and stackoverflow and mongoDB community they mentioned theere use ISODate or new Date()

Comment: Yes, if your fromDate, toDate is proper Date object, you will get the desired o/p

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand the build-in methods you can create by functions names

```
@Repository
public interface YourDTORepository extends MongoRepository<YourDTO, YourIdentifier> {
    ArrayList<YourDTO> findByCreatedAtBetween(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
}
```

Between expecting for two parameters and it will build the range for you.

Comment: I have to use Aggregation like mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "collectionName", myDTO.class);

Answer (score 1):

After lots of researh finally, I got the solution, probably this will help others.

```
"createdAt" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2020-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2022-01-04T07:34:42.000Z"}}}}
```

This is returned by mongoDbTemplate is right but it's not supporting the older version of spring boot.

My project older version was

```
<pom>
    <groupId>com.Demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>emp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
</pom>
```

I change it as follows

```
 <pom>
        <groupId>com.Demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>emp</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
  </pom>
```

The rest of the code is the same as above.

So it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was stuck at a place since long time this answer resolved my issue. Thanks Uttam Pawar.